# Only display plot legends for curves that are visible in the plot range

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a list of coefficients, i.e. `coefficients = {{a1,a2},{b1,b2},...,{an,bn}}`

From this, I generate a list of functions.

I then plot these functions with a specified plot range, and add plot legends which are labelled by the coefficients.

My question is: How do I only show plot legends for those functions which appear within the plot range?

My code so far:

```
coefficients = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 0, 5}];
functions = #1 + Cos[#2 x] & @@@ coefficients;
Plot[Evaluate@functions, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, PlotLegends -> ToString /@ coefficients]
```

In the resulting plot below we see more legends than curves.

[image: The plot resulting from the code above. We see only some plots in the specified plot range, but plot legends displayed for all functions.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit by OP.** Here is the full working code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
coefficients = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 0, 5}];
functions = #1 + Cos[#2 x] & @@@ coefficients;
p = Plot[Evaluate@functions, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, PlotLegends -> ToString /@ coefficients];

memberQ = MemberQ[p[[1]], #, Infinity] & /@ p[[2, 1, 1]];
positions = Position[memberQ, False];
p[[2, 1, 1]] = Delete[p[[2, 1, 1]], positions];
p
```

`p[[2,1,1]]` returns the list of graphics elements which correspond to the coloured curves. `MemberQ` is used to test `p[[1]]` (which is the displayed plot) as to which coloured curves are displayed. It returns a list of `True` and `False` values. I then use `Position` to return the positions in `p[[2,1,1]]` of the curves that are not displayed. Then I update `p[[2,1,1]]` and finally re-display `p`. Here is the result

[image: Result of the code block above]

**Original post that solved most of the problem**

I do not know how to do it properly but you can check if a color exists by doing

```
coefficients = Table[{x, RandomReal[]}, {x, 0, 5}];
functions = #1 + Cos[#2 x] & @@@ coefficients;
p = Plot[Evaluate@functions, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, PlotLegends -> ToString /@ coefficients]

MemberQ[p[[1]], yourColor, Infinity]
```

you find the colours in the legend by checking p[[2,1,1,i,2]] for all valid i.
If the check returns False you can Delete the entry from the legend. You could use DeleteCases for that but i cannot get that to work right now for lack of time. In spirit it should look like:

```
p[[2,1,1]] = DeleteCases[p[[2,1,1]], MemberQ[p[[1]], #[[2,2]], Infinity]&]
```

but where there is a pattern instead of a test.

Answer (score 4):

An analytical solution would check if the functions were in range of the y-plot range over the domain of the x-plot range.  You may use region functions like `ImplicitRegion`, `RegionIntersection`, and `RegionMeasure` to achieve this.

```
ClearAll[x, y];
emptyIntersection[foos_, domain_, range_] :=
 Position[
  Map[RegionMeasure[#, 1] &,
   RegionIntersection[
      ImplicitRegion[FunctionRange[{#, Between[domain]@x}, x, y], y],
      ImplicitRegion[Between[range]@y, {y}]
      ] & /@ foos],
  0]
```

`emptyIntersection` performs such a check when given a list of equations and the domain and range of the plot and returns the positions of the functions that are not in the range.

With `functions` as in OP then

```
emptyIntersection[functions, {-2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {2, 4}]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {6}}
> ```

The `LegendLayout` option of `LineLegend` can be used to `Delete` the legend of functions not in range.

```
Plot[functions, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> {2, 4},
 PlotLegends ->
  LineLegend[Automatic, ToString /@ coefficients,
   LegendLayout -> (Grid[
       Delete[#, emptyIntersection[functions, {-2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {2, 4}]]] &)
   ]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

It also works well with `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[functions, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> plotrange,
  PlotLegends ->
   LineLegend[Automatic, ToString /@ coefficients,
    LegendLayout -> (Grid[
        Delete[#, 
         emptyIntersection[{-2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, plotrange]]] &)
    ]
  ],
 {{plotrange, {-1, 0}}, 
  IntervalSlider[#, {-1, 6, .1}, MinIntervalSize -> 1, 
    Method -> "Push"] &}
 ]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice. My suggestions would be to wrap `emptyIntersection` in a `Module` (or something similar) to make it easily reusable with other variables (aside from `x` and `y`), i.e. `emptyIntersection[foos_, domain_, range_, x_] := Module[{y}, YOUR CODE]`

Comment: @Tom Yeah, I was using formal symbols but FunctionRange was joy cooperating with them. Which reminds me that I need to post that to WRI Support.